# Makefile: automatic target in other directories

Tags: makefile

in a current C project we've had the bad idea of putting all object files to a different folder from the source. It wasn't complicate to manage at first, but now we need to compile some files in a specific folder and other in another.

The arborecence looks like:

- objs1
- objs2
- src

  - file1.c
  - file2.c

After running `make` I'd like the arborescence to be modified as:

- objs1

  - file1.o
- objs2

  - file1.o
  - file2.o

At first the makefile was like:

```
CSRC = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(CSRC:%.c=%.o)

objs1/%.o : %.c
  gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

Now theres also file2.c and it should not be compiled in objs1, file1.o should be in both objs1 and objs2 and file2.o should be in objs2.

I use generic rules because the project is bigger and it is really convenient.

So I have two variables wich contains the name of objects, one for objs1, the other for objs2.

I'd like to do something like

```
$(OBJS1): %.o %.c
```

But it would act like source files are in objs1 and that's not the case.

So what's the way to combine generic rules with specified location ?

Thank you

Comment: How do `objs1/file1.o` and `objs2/file1.o` differ if they are compiled from the same source file? Are they complied with different options?

Comment: Yes they are, one is compiled as standard object and the other is compiled with binding to JNI first and then as a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to specify the objects manually seeing as you need specific files compiled in specific directories:

```
objs1 := objs1/file1.o
objs2 := objs2/file1.o objs2/file2.o

$(objs1): CFLAGS += blah1
$(objs2): CFLAGS += blah2

$(objs1): objs1/%.o: src/%.c
$(objs2): objs2/%.o: src/%.c

$(objs1) $(objs2):
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

If the small amount of duplication is annoying you, you can use secondary expansion instead

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(objs1) $(objs2): %.o: src/$$(notdir $$*).c
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

Answer (score 1):

If you tolerate recursive make, you might make your respective subdirectory
quotas of object files just by making *in* the subdirectory, with the
appropriate `CFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` and [`VPATH=../src`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html)
No need to write any compilation recipes at all in that case, e.g.

**Makefile**

```
export CC := gcc
objs1: OBJS := file1.o
objs2: OBJS := file1.o file2.o
objs1: CFLAGS := -g
objs1: CPPFLAGS := -I../include  
objs2: CFLAGS = -O2
objs2: CPPFLAGS := -I../include -DNDEBUG

.PHONY: all clean objs1 objs2

all: objs1 objs2

objs1 objs2:
    mkdir -p $@
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(OBJS) CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)' CPPFLAGS='$(CPPFLAGS)' VPATH=../src

clean:
    rm -fr objs1 objs2
```

which runs like:

```
$ make
mkdir -p objs1
make -C objs1 file1.o CFLAGS='-g' CPPFLAGS='-I../include  ' VPATH=../src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/imk/develop/scrap/objs1'
gcc -g -I../include    -c -o file1.o ../src/file1.c
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/imk/develop/scrap/objs1'
mkdir -p objs2
make -C objs2 file1.o file2.o CFLAGS='-O2' CPPFLAGS='-I../include -DNDEBUG' VPATH=../src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/imk/develop/scrap/objs2'
gcc -O2 -I../include -DNDEBUG  -c -o file1.o ../src/file1.c
gcc -O2 -I../include -DNDEBUG  -c -o file2.o ../src/file2.c
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/imk/develop/scrap/objs2'
```

It's important that the subdirectories are `.PHONY`. Otherwise, `make` will
reckon their mere existence means there's nothing to do.